# Unity Rigidbody2D stick to Platform which is moving horizontal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
I have a player and a level that moves horizontally. If the player lands on a platform, the platform moves, but the player stays on his position and does not move with it.

Do you know a way to get around this and have the player move with the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hayo, the simplest solution would be to make the player a child object of whatever object he is standing on, this way any movement of the platform would also be applied to the player.

Comment: Thanks. Have now implemented it like this and it works.